# What is Fox doing when he is on the phone with Scully?

Tags: the-x-files

In X-Files S5E10 "Chinga", Scully calls Mulder on the phone from Maine in order to ask him questions about the doll case she's working on. In the background of the call, Scully asks him what he's watching on TV in his office, and he casually says something along the lines of "World's Deadliest Swarms". Clearly the voices heard are of female persuasion, and the moans and groans sound as if he's watching pornography. At the same time, Mulder's hand is not visible on his desk or on the phone. Are we to believe that Mulder was masturbating in his office? If so, what would the repercussions be for an FBI agent of his caliber?

Comment: repercussions? Higher ratings for X-files from all the lonely nerds.

Comment: They'll give him the basement office and treat him with no respect. Oh, right.

Comment: Strong parallels between this and Runcle's work actions in Californication...

Comment: I've never seen the episode (and doubt Fox was pleasuring himself, plot-wise), but I find the question interesting /amusing in light of what the episode title means to many non-english speakers...

Comment: If you're able to see it (e.g. Netflix? don't know...), go for it. It's a really great episode all around "Scully on her own".

Comment: It's not really that far-fetched as it's a "known secret" that Mulder is very much into porn.

Comment: I love this kind of humour in X-Files, it's really well done and very entertaining. One of my favourite episodes is, basically, a full episode of this strange comical intrigue and misdirection. It's ***Jose Chung's From Outer Space*** (S3 E20) but also, ***Bad Blood***, ***War of the Coprophages*** and more, they all have this fantastic comic intrigue that I love.

Answer (score 10):

from [transcript](http://www.insidethex.co.uk/transcrp/scrp510.htm) - scene 3:

> (X-Files office. Mulder is eating sunflower seeds and watching television. Lots of groaning and moaning from a male and a female voice. Empty video cassette box on MULDER’S desk reads "Alien Probe." Phone rings.)

and:

> MULDER switches off TV, which now shows man being attacked by bugs

Comment: I think this is just one of the many "casual Mulder" scenes trying to lure the viewer into thinking of some "ah, we all knew it", which is then revealed as some "hah, got you, it's not!" moments (which is kind of opposite of the show's general promise, considering there's almost always some monster of the week or some conspiracy (sub) plot). While I can't name any other out of my mind, there have been quite a few throughout the series.

Comment: "Alien Probe" could sound like a porno. Maybe his work was getting to him :P

Answer (score 10):

In the scene you described, Mulder **is** watching "World's deadliest swarms" while talking to Scully and eating sunflower seeds.

Mulder's hand is momentarily visible behind the desk and you can see that he is cracking open the sunflower seeds. Then the phone rings and he picks it up. **He is definitely not masturbating** while eating sunflower seeds.

During the telephonic conversation between Scully & Mulder, you can see there are two television sets: one that Mulder is watching & the other on which Scully is seeing the CCTV footage of the store.

If you have the same version of episode I have then at 7'37" you can see the footage of a man being attacked by a swarm of bees.

Here is the scene:

> [***Mulder's office***. Mulder sitting on his chair behind his desk & eating sunflower seeds while watching TV. Man, Woman Moaning on TV]
>
> [Phone Rings, Mulder pics up.]
>
> **Mulder:** Mulder!
>
> **Scully:** Mulder, It's me.
>
> [Moaning continues on TV]
>
> **Mulder:** I thought you were on vacation.
>
> **Scully:** I am, I am up in Maine.
>
> **Mulder:** I thought you said you didn't want to be disturbed. You wanted to get out of your head for a few days.
>
> **Scully:** I don't. I mean, I do. I... uh...
>
> [Moaning grows louder on TV.]
>
> **Scully:** What are you watching, Mulder?
>
> **Mulder:** It's the "World's Deadliest Swarms." Um--  You said you were gonna be unreachable. What's going on?
>
> [Mulder picks up the remote and mutes the TV]
>
> [In ***Market's security office*** now. Scully & Sheriff watching the CCTV footage.]
>
> **Scully:** I, Uh-- I'm at a market here. I'm just trying to give the local P.D. a handle here.
>
> **Mulder:** A handle on what?
>
> **Scully:** Well.. I'm not quite sure how to describe it, Mulder. I didn't witness it myself, but there seems to be some kind of an outbreak of people acting in a violent, involuntary way.
>
> [CCTV footage shows what Scully is describing]
>
> [***Mulder's office*** again. Mulder walking towards TV.]
>
> **Mulder:** Towards who?
>
> **Scully:** Toward themselves.
>
> **[ON MULDER'S TV, A MAN IS BEING ATTACKED BY BEES. MAN IS KNEELING DOWN AND IS IN PAIN. MULDER THEN TURNS OFF THE TV.]**
>
> **Mulder:** Themselves ?
>
> **Scully:** Yeah. Beating at their faces; clawing at their eyes.
>
> [Market Security office again.]
>
> **Scully:** One man is dead.
>
> [CCTV footage shows people attacking themselves]
>
> **Mulder:** Dead how ?
>
> **Scully:** Self-inflicted, it appears.
>
> **Mulder:** Huh.  It sounds to me like that's, uh, witchcraft or maybe some sorcery that you're looking for there.
>
> **Scully:** No, i don't think It's witchcraft, Mulder, Or sorcery.
>
> [Sheriff amused by Mulder's Ideas.]
>
> **Scully:** I've had a look around, And I don't see any evidence of anything that warrants that kind of suspicion.
>
> **Mulder:** Maybe you don't know what you're looking for.
>
> **Scully:** Like evidence of conjury, or the black arts or shamanism, divination, wicca, or any kind of pagan or neo-pagan practice. Charms, cards, familiars, Bloodstones or hex signs or any of the ritual tableau associated with the occult, santeria, Voudom, macumba or any high or low magic.
>
> **Mulder:** Scully?
>
> **Scully:** Yes?
>
> **Mulder:** Marry me.
>
> **Scully:** I was hoping for something a little more helpful.
>
> **Mulder:** Short of looking for a lady wearing a pointy hat, riding a broomstick, I think you've pretty much got it covered there.
>
> **Scully:** Thanks anyway.

Comment: Pretty sure he changed it to the swarm show.